# Appium Go To URL is not working

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

As per appium libary `Go To URL` must open the url in default browser
But its not working.

```
Go To URL   http://m.webapp.com
```

*Note:*
This is an example in appium library.

Thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? Does the keyword say it succeeds but the browser doesn't open? Does the wrong browser open? Does the program crash? Does the test crash?

Comment: Can you please share some error or explain "What is not working". hard to answer anything by just looking at your question

Comment: The browser is not opening

Answer (score 1):

At Robot I've added variable where to pass the result and then it worked:

```
${web1}=    Go To Url   http://m.webapp.com
```

Comment: it not working for me.plz tell me the version you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using adb(android device bridge) & shell as well.

```
./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Now the url will get launched in the default browser of android.

FYI:

*adb* -> To connect the device

*am* -> Activity Manager

*shell* ->  start the terminal (command line) on the device/emulator

use the keyword `execute` to run adb